# 301 Redirects Appends ?p=original/url/path - how can I remove?

Tags: url, redirect, redirection

Whether I'm using the Reroute plugin or plugging it in .htaccess, changing the path elsewhere appends the query in the end. How can I remove?

```
Redirect 301 /blog/category /blog/archive
```

Is the line I have in my .htaccess

So if I go to:

http://domain.com/blog/category/category-name

it takes me to:

http://domain.com/blog/archive/category-name?p=blog/category/category-name

What's going on here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue here is that your `Redirect` directive is conflicting with Craft’s index.php-hiding `RewriteRule` directive. *(`Redirect` is a [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) directive and `RewriteRule` is a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) directive. They’re two separate modules that can be used for the same thing, but lead to unexpected consequences when used together.)*

To fix this, use a `RewriteRule` directive for your own custom redirects as well, rather than `Redirect`.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category(/.*)?$ /blog/archive$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure that you place that ***before*** Craft’s redirect.

Comment: That gives me a 404 :(

Comment: Is this meant to be in ADDITION instead of replacement? If it's in addition, I added the original Redirect above and then the one you have up there with the rewrite it still appends the URL

Comment: Should be a replacement. Old code out. This is what I used on an EE project where I was having this problem.

Comment: Make sure you place that _before_ Craft’s redirect.

Comment: Yes, mine is right after "RewriteEngine on". Adding that to my answer.

Comment: Noticed that this works if it's just /blog/category — it will redirect to /blog/archive. However, I need it to redirect when something is after it. e.g. /blog/category/category-name to /blog/archive/category-name

Comment: @lealea Ah, didn’t realize that’s what you wanted. Just updated the code.

Answer (score 6):

One way you can avoid this is by making a small change to the htaccess rules for removing index.php from Craft URLs. You can remove the query string from `RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` and replace it with `/$1`

So the full set of rules to remove index.php would be

```
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This seems to work fine in my test and prevents the query string from being appended to the URL when using `Redirect 301` in htaccess.

Comment: In my tests, this seems to work! However, what are the possible side-effects of removing the ?p=

Comment: The only side effect of that change is it won’t work on servers that don’t support PATH_INFO. If it looks like it’s working for you, then great!

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you add a `?` to the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category?$ /blog/archive [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Still gave me a 404

Comment: When you put a `?` right after another character in a regular expression, you’re just saying that whatever came before it is optional. So that pattern would match both “blog/category” and “blog/categor”. (Usually it’s good idea to put a `?` right before a trailing slash, so you’re matching both “blog/category/” and “blog/category”.)

Comment: s/right before a trailing slash/right after a trailing slash/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove these from search results, you may find this helpful: [Remove Query Strings from URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071671/remove-query-string-from-end-of-url-url-using-htaccess)