# Why am I getting ?p=oldpage in a 301 redirect?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Not sure whether this is directly related to Craft but I’ve been using this method for years and it has always worked with other sites.

I’m replacing an old site and some pages have moved. I want to redirect any old pages to the new url since there are already indexed.

I’m using a simple redirect 301
Redirect 301 /work/project-name http://www.mysite.com/case-studies

I’m getting http://www.mysite.com/case-studies/project-name?p=work/project-name and of course a page not found since this is not where I intended the page to go.

Comment: Just a hunch, but try setting [`omitScriptNameInUrls`](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#omitScriptNameInUrls) to `true` in your config file.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately that didn’t change anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Craft works by taking requests that normally would 404—because they don't actually exist on the server but in the database. The piece that makes this happen is the rewrite rules.

It's helpful to look at Craft's `.htaccess` file line-by-line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The request must not already exist and the file is not already an existing directory on the server.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
```

The URL must not be favicon.ico, apple-touch-icon.whatever.png. The `NC` at the end means no-case (meaning case-insenstive).

```
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is the rule that actually fires. Take those would-be 404s, redirect to /index.php (the controller). `$1` means the match found in `(.+)`.

The `QSA` flag means query string append. This is the part that's actually causing you issues. (You could remove it but get URLs with parameters called from controllers might not work in certain situations.)

`L` means last; if this rule is applied, it won't process anything else. Doesn't matter here unless you have other rules.

What you need to do is tell Apache to exclude this particular request from Craft's processing (put it after the favicon rule):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(work/project-name)$ [NC]
```

Now what will happen is your Redirect 301 rule will fire by itself. Since `/case-studies` doesn't actually exist on the server,  Apache is going to send that rule *back* to Craft and fire like any normal "page" which is what you want.

If you have other redirected 301s from the old `/work` section, you might do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(work/.+)$ [NC]
```

That will let Craft know not to touch any of your 301s in the old work section. You still need your old `Redirect 301` rules.  (You could make a `RewriteRule` for those if you wanted to simply things but this will get you going.)

Your completed file would look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(work/.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

Redirect 301 /work/project-name http://www.mysite.com/case-studies
...
```

I find some browsers will "cache"  an old page/redirect for awhile. To confirm it's actually working you might want to use `curl -I http://site/work/project-name`. If you see "moved permanently" message, you're all set.

Comment: this doesn’t seem to work for me.

What I’m trying to do is to redirect old pages (which are non-existent now) to new ones. /work is now /case-studies. anything preceded by /work/ can go to /case-studies too.

I thought this was going to be simple and straightforward.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
 
 RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]



 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 Redirect 301 /work /case-studies
 Redirect 301 /work/the-cake-decorator /case-studies
 Redirect 301 /work/cream-co /case-studies/ 
 Redirect 301 /work/josies /case-studies
 Redirect 301 /work/head-smash /case-studies
 Redirect 301 /profile/seven-ideas /profile
</IfModule>

Comment: You want to make sure ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(work/.+)$ [NC]`` is included. I've updated my answer above with a more complete example.

Comment: @RitterKnight Thank you for the interesting explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found this solution:

Instead of `Redirect 301` use a `RewriteRule` instead:

`RewriteRule ^/work/project-name(/.*)?$ /case-studies$1 [R=301,L]`

Insert this **before** Craft's Rewrite rules and it should work.

Credit where credit is due: This solution [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/940/5424) and it is from [Anna-Mediagirl](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/103/anna-mediagirl)